# Show graphic next to a textbox if it failed validation

Tags: model-view-controller, validation

I have a simple MVC form: First name, Email Address which are both required. If the user hits the submit button I would like to display a graphic next to the textboxes that failed validation.

I am using Data Annotations and Validation summary already.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
//ViewModelClass
public class yourViewModel
{
//...
bool showPictureName {get;set;}
}
//controller
{
//...
var NameErrors = ModelState["yourViewModel.Name"].Errors;
if(!Modelstate.IsValid)
{
// put your code here
if(NameErrors.Count() != 0)

yourViewModelObject.showPictureName = true;
}
}
//View
@{ if(Model.showPictureName == true)
<img .../>
}
```